# DB upgrade utility stalls at 5.11.alpha1

Tags: upgrade

I was updating from 5.9.0 to 5.13.2 and the DB upgrade utility stalled at 5.11.alpha1. Anyone else have this experience? How can I troubleshoot? (Did not have this problem with our dev site.)

Joomla 3.9.5

This is from ConfigAndLog. Now, what can I do with it? Note error in backtrace line #6:

```
May 07 12:09:00  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.11.alpha1: SQL

May 07 12:09:01  [info] Running task: Update smart groups where jcalendar fields have been converted to datepicker

May 07 12:11:08  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => exceptionHandler
    )

[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => 
    SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.payment_processor_type_id as `payment_processor_type_id`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_default as `is_default`, a.is_test as `is_test`, a.user_name as `user_name`, a.password as `password`, a.signature as `signature`, a.url_site as `url_site`, a.url_api as `url_api`, a.url_recur as `url_recur`, a.url_button as `url_button`, a.subject as `subject`, a.class_name as `class_name`, a.billing_mode as `billing_mode`, a.is_recur as `is_recur`, a.payment_type as `payment_type`, a.payment_instrument_id as `payment_instrument_id`, a.accepted_credit_cards as `accepted_credit_cards`
    FROM civicrm_payment_processor a
    WHERE (a.is_active = "1") AND (a.domain_id = "1")
    ORDER BY a.is_default DESC, a.name
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.title' in 'field list']
**array repeats this info in different forms**

May 07 12:11:08  [info] $backTrace = #0 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(952): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#3 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#4 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'a.title' in 'field list'")
#7 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#9 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#10 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#11 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(439): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#12 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1414): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...", TRUE)
#13 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/SelectQuery.php(144): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.domain_id as `domain_id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as...")
#14 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php(1253): Civi\API\SelectQuery->run()
#15 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/PaymentProcessor.php(93): _civicrm_api3_basic_get("CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor", (Array:5))
#16 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(101): civicrm_api3_payment_processor_get((Array:5))
#17 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(168): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#18 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(99): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#19 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(43): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("payment_processor", "get", (Array:5))
#20 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php(299): civicrm_api3("payment_processor", "get", (Array:5))
#21 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php(376): CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getAllPaymentProcessors("all")
#22 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php(440): CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPaymentProcessors((Array:1))
#23 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php(467): CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::hasPaymentProcessorSupporting((Array:1))
#24 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Block.php(370): CRM_Core_Config::isEnabledBackOfficeCreditCardPayments()
#25 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Block.php(290): CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateShortcutValues()
#26 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Block.php(617): CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues(1)
#27 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Joomla.php(67): CRM_Core_Block::getContent(1)
#28 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(208): CRM_Core_Joomla::sidebarLeft()
#29 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#30 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#31 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#32 /joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#33 /joomla/path/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#34 /joomla/path/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/joomla/path/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#35 /joomla/path/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#36 /joomla/path/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#37 /joomla/path/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#38 /joomla/path/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#39 {main}
```

([This question is not my problem.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30486/upgrade-from-5-11-0-to-5-12-failing-database-update-solution-found))

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just spinning?

Comment: Just spinning. No error. My understanding is that the DB upgrade utility doesn't log, so I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: You can refresh the page. Sometimes the upgrade will just timeout on one task, but a refresh will restart the timer. Also have you tried running the upgrade using CV on the commandline?

Comment: Check the log file - eg `sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/...`  Are there any errors in there since the start of the upgrade?  What were the last entries?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that, Aidan. I added the lines in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in question was added in CiviCRM 5.13.0.  It looks like during your upgrade process, Joomla is trying to show a CiviCRM block in the left sidebar which is expecting to already be upgraded.

I would recommend either temporarily disabling the CiviCRM block(s) in the sidebar, or upgrading to Civi 5.12.4 before upgrading to 5.13.0.

Comment: Worked perfectly stepping up to 5.12.4 before going on to 5.13.5.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful. Most of those civi blocks get enabled automatically and are annoying, so I just use update blocks set status = 1 where module = 'civicrm' and then the db update can complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.  Looking at the error in the log, line 6 of the backtrace, it indicates the "title" field does not exist.  I went into the database schema and added  the field, thinking that would allow it to continue.  However, now when I run the database upgrade I get an error indicating that the database seems to be partially upgraded.  Will continue to pursue.