# Joomla 3.9.6 - Civicrm 5.12.2 to 5.13.4 failed

Tags: upgrade, failure

I have just attempted to update to 5.13.4 and at an early stage of process it stalled and now whilst I can still access Joomla backend but the Civicrm has failed. On clicking civi now get this warning -

> CiviCRM-001   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. DB Error: no such field
>
> [Return to home page.](https://secure.communist-party.org.uk/administrator/)
>
> function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: What was the error you got during the install? If you didn't catch the error during the install check on your logs. I'm not sure anyone can help with the error you gave.

Comment: If you lost the error given during the install you may want to just try again. Otherwise you may need to rollback from a backup. I had a similar problem with upgrading recently. It ended up being the collation of one of my tables wouldn't accept a country name with odd characters. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30486/upgrade-from-5-11-0-to-5-12-failing-database-update-solution-found

Comment: Problems with my account meant I continued this post here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/civicrm-failed-upgrade